# Difference between Azure App Services and Web App for Containers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, containers, azure-web-app-service

I was looking to use [Azure App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) and noticed Azure now offers [Web App for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/resources/videos/web-app-for-containers-overview/), now I wonder what's the difference between them? And couple more questions come to my mind

- Assuming I choose Web App for Containers, who is going to manage the container updates?
- Is the deployment differs from App Services to Web App for Containers, from application perspective?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Web App for Containers is one of the offerings in Azure App Service. It allows you to deploy containerized applications on Linux and Windows (the latter is [in preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-windows-container-support-in-azure-app-service/)).

The platform automatically takes care of OS patching, capacity provisioning, and load balancing. But, the container updates are up to you.

The deployment differs in that you will be deploying your application inside a Docker container instead of deploying directly like you do in a Web App.

Comment: With common azure app service it is also aavailable to deploy container